# Posftfix mysteries

Tags: postfix

I hope someone can help me with this one. Posftix, on an OpenSuse 10.3
(old due to specific configuration - client doesn't want to change
now) sends mail "on behalf of" root@net.net, and I can't figure out
why, or how it does it.

The problem is, a lot of mails now bounce, or gets blocked by the
other mail servers.
I checked all the options in the posftix main.cf file, as well as the
/etc/aliases file, and see no entries for root@net.net.
/etc/hosts doesn't have it either.

Here's a sample of the maillog:

```
Oct 23 17:30:04 ser001 postfix/pickup[5534]: 0367678BF3: uid=0 from=<root>
Oct 23 17:30:04 ser001 postfix/cleanup[5550]: 0367678BF3:
message-id=<20111023153004.0367678BF3@rewards.x.x>
Oct 23 17:30:04 ser001 postfix/qmgr[5537]: 0367678BF3:
from=<root@net.net>, size=2168, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 23 17:30:04 ser001 postfix/smtp[5644]: 0367678BF3:
to=<root@net.net>, orig_to=<root>, relay=rewards.x.x[196.34.x.x]:25,
delay=2.6, delays=2.4/0/0.15/0.09, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host
rewards.x.x[196.34.x.x] said: 530 Relaying not allowed - sender domain
not local (in reply to end of DATA command))



root@ser001:[~]$ whoami
root
root@ser001:[~]$ hostname
ser001
root@ser001:[~]$ domainname

root@ser001:[~]$ env | grep net.net
root@ser001:[~]$
```

The server is setup to use a smarthost to relay mail, but even if I
change it to another one, it still sends mail on behalf of
root@net.net

Interestingly, when I login to the shell as a normal user, and send
email (either via the commandline, or Mutt), it sends the mail from
{user}@net.net.
Yet, in Mutt, I can see it shows that mail comes from {user}@rewards.x.x

Does anyone know what causes this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In your `main.cf` you have a line with `myorigin = net.net`. That is the problem.

If not we need the output of `postconf -n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -ir "net.net" /etc/postfix` and see if something like address masquerading is set in Postfix.

SMTP envelopes can be completely different thing from mail headers (which can include `From:` that Mutt parses).

In real world, you can write `John Doe` as sender name in envelope, but then the actual letter found inside the envelope can contain your real name.